# How is it possible to take an exponential of a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: c, matlab, math, porting

I have a MATLAB code which I have to convert to C language. According to the MATLAB code,

```
n1 = 11; x1 = randn(2,n1) + repmat([-1 1]’,1,n1);
w = [0 0]’;
```

here acccording to my calculation, the output of

```
w’*x1
```

will be a 1x3 matrix, that is a row vector as far as I know.

Then what will be the output of the following code,

```
z = exp(repmat(b,1,n1)+w’*x1);
```

where `repmat()` also creates a 1xn1 matrix (I'm not sure about this, figured it out from manual). My understanding is that addition of two 1x3 matrices will not give a scalar.

How is an exponential is taken here? Can exponential be applied to a matrix?

Comment: You can raise e to the power of a *square* matrix. But that's mathematics, I don't know about Matlab.

Comment: can you post the result of 

repmat(b,1,n1)+w'*x1
 . In octave it does not work. The first term is 4x11, the second 1x11

Comment: Thnx for your input. So what will be the value of e raised to a matrix? Another matrix or a single scalar value?

Comment: It is not even remotely impossible. Very possible in fact.

Comment: @user1031962 - It all depends on how you define it. In matlab, exp(A), where A is an array computes an element-wise exponential. There is also expm, which computes the matrix exponential.

Comment: I'm not sure about the result of any of the statements. I never worked with Matlab code before. All I know is what i read from the Matlab manual.  [link](http://www.mathworks.in/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like many MATLAB functions, the `exp` function operates element-wise when applied to arrays. For further details, please refer to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/exp.html).

Comment: So according to my code, z will be an array of exponential values.?

Comment: Yes. When converting to C you need to turn it into a loop that calls exp() for each element of the input matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply exponentation to a matrix. From the Wikipedia article: [Matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)

> Let X be an n×n real or complex matrix. The exponential of X, denoted by e<sup>X</sup> or exp(X), is the n×n matrix given by the power series

```
e^X = Sum(k=0, infinity) 1/k! * X^k
```

As @John Bartholomew pointed though, this is not what the `exp()` of Matlab does.

Comment: While this is true, it is not what the MATLAB `exp` function does (MATLAB does have a function to calculate the matrix exponential, but it's called `expm`, presumably because it's less commonly useful than scalar `exp`)